# Mybatis return %rowtype of cursor

Tags: java, oracle, cursor, mybatis

i'm working with oracle database and have no problems with running simple selects with mybatis, but i need to use cursor(is allows me to get different task in different threads with update skip locked option), but i'm facing the problem with getting result out of mybatis(i can't find a way to get this data in java), here is a little simplified script(removed lot of unimportant columns/tables):

```
<select id="getNewListSafe" resultType="Map">
  declare
    cursor tasks is
      select
      t.ID,
      t.SYS_ID
      from TASK t
      order by t.PRIORITY
      for update skip locked;
    TYPE rows_array IS VARRAY(5) OF tasks%rowtype;
    result_array rows_array;
    BEGIN
      OPEN tasks;
      fetch tasks BULK COLLECT into result_array LIMIT 5;;
      --return result_array; -- any way i can do that?
    END;
</select>
```

This is probably a silly question, but i already spend a lot of time googling and still dont get if i need some kind of parameter/result map, this looks too complicated, please help, i am a little desperate right now.

Comment: I don't think you can "return" anything from an anonymous block; you may want to consider using a stored procedure or function instead.

Comment: 1st you should try to try pure JDBC. Use callable statement with out parameter.